# Instagram iPhone hooks url schemes

Tags: ios

I have developed an app to test the use of Instagram iPhone hooks, which is quite well explained on this site, but, to my opinion, not so on the Instagram developer site. The reason for this post is to see if there are developers better informed than I am about the url scheme and parameters in the iPhone hooks than I am.

According to Instagram you can use the following urls:
[image]

However, it is not clear to me what the Instagram app does depending on the url. The reason is that I first, of course, used the scheme and url:

```
let instagramURL = URL.init(string: "instagram://app")
```

Then I tried tho use:

```
let instagramURL = URL.init(string: "instagram://location?id=1")
```

Same behavior. So, I went further and used:

```
let instagramURL = URL.init(string: "instagram://location")
let instagramURL = URL.init(string: "instagram://layout")
let instagramURL = URL.init(string: "instagram://crap")
```

All delivering the same successful behavior in being able to post a picture on Instagram. I reported the issue with this question on the developers site, but haven't gotten a response yet.

Is there someone with a better understanding of the url schemes used in the iPhone hooks?

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't get what exactly you are looking for but,
Using these schemes you can open a specific location , tag or username's page directly on instagram app
try this for example : "instagram://user?username=amirzakeri" :)